# handling exceptions in settrace 'return' calls

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 2.x, the frame object passed into a [`settrace`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.settrace) handler had an `f_exc_type` attribute.

In Python 3.x, this `f_exc_type` has been removed.

If a function is propagating an exception, the trace 'return' is called but the argument is `None` and `sys.exc_info()` is `(None,None,None)`.  This is described in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/sys.html#sys.settrace):

> `[return]`A function (or other code block) is about to return. The local trace
>   function is called; arg is the value that will be returned, or None if
>   the event is caused by an exception being raised. The trace function’s
>   return value is ignored.

In Python 3, how can a tracer determine in a `return`  hook that an exception is being propagated?  How can it differentiate it from a function returning `None` normally?

Answer (score 5):

This does seem fairly broken.  It's a bit of a hack, but you can tell the difference by looking at the bytecode for the last instruction:

```
import opcode

def tracer(frame, event, arg):
    if event == 'return':
        if arg is not None or (opcode.opname[frame.f_code.co_code[frame.f_lasti]]
                               in ('RETURN_VALUE', 'YIELD_VALUE')):
            print('exit via return', arg)
        else:
            print('exit via exception')
```

Comment: makes me shiver but it does work!  Thank you!  https://github.com/williame/obiwan/commit/b67a9c02efb38ccad1aec417c324a1ceb8a9a46f

Comment: This is good but I found a case where it doesn't work - if you return None inside a `try` block with a `finally` clause then it will exit after finishing the finally block and the opcode will be END_FINALLY so this code will report an exception. But I don't see a perfect solution because that opcode will also happen if an exception is raised inside the `try`.